# Reference XML Integer Resource from inside String Resource

Tags: android, resources

Is it possible to reference an xml integer resource, inside a string resource?

For example: I'm storing a regular expression as a string resource, 
but I need to include integer values in my regular expression, 
and these integer values are already stored as integer resources.

Answer (score 1):

Check this documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

One way to achieve what you want is using %d in your string and substitute it with the value of another integer resource in code -- see the section Quantity Strings (Plurals) on the site for an example.